# Let $P$ be a polyhedron. Prove, $P$ has at least one extreme point $\iff$ $P$ does not contain a line, by using a lemma.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Let $P$ be a polyhedron. Prove, $P$ has at least one extreme point $\iff$ $P$ does not contain a line, by using a lemma.

I've a Lemma saying:

Suppose $P=P(V,E)$ where $V,E \in \mathbb R^n$ are finite sets. If $0_n$ (zero) is not an extreme point of $\text {cone}(E)$, then $P$ has no extreme points.

I should then look at when $P$ contain a line vs. when $0_n$ is an extreme point of $\text{cone}(E)$.

I've found the following:

$$\exists \ \text {extreme point} \ x \in P \Rightarrow 0_n \ \text {is an extreme point of  cone}(E)$$

$$0_n \ \text {is an extreme point of  cone}(E) \Rightarrow \forall  \ v \in V  \ (v\text { is an extreme point of } P)$$

$$0_n \ \text {is an extreme point of  cone}(E) \Rightarrow \forall  \ e \in E  \ (e\text { is an extreme direction of } P)$$

However, I cannot conclude the above statement from this.

Help is appreciated !

Comment: What does the notation $P(V,E)$ mean?

Comment: Note: from the context of the question it is clear that convexity is assumed. (For instance, Boyd & Vandenberghe define a polyhedron as the intersection of linear inequalities.) Note however that in other contexts a polyedron may not in fact be convex, in which case this statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: It means the polyhedron generated by $\text {conv}(V) + \text {cone}(E)$. Michael, do you have any idea how to solve this ?